# I'd rather not [do something] vs I'd prefer not to [do something]

Tags: formality

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42292/polite-way-to-refuse-to-answer-a-question) the issue came up as to whether there's any difference in the level of politeness/correctness involved in *I'd rather not say* as opposed to *I'd prefer not to say*.

My own gut feeling is the *prefer* form is a bit more "formal" (and thus arguably more correct/polite). [This NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=I%27d%20rather,I%27d%20prefer&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that *I'd rather* occurs far more often than *I'd prefer*. Partly that's just because the *rather* form is more common, but the difference is far less marked with the more formal [I would rather/prefer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=I%20would%20rather,I%20would%20prefer&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). I take this to mean *rather* is more suited to casual use/conversation when used with this meaning.

It could be lots of verbs besides *say*, and I don't think the *not* is necessarily relevant here either. But usages vary for certain alternatives - for example, *go blind* only seems to work with *rather*.

That's just my opinion. Does anyone have arguments/evidence/sources to either back up or refute the proposition that *I'd prefer not to say* is more formal than *I'd rather not say*?

Comment: I can't say I've noticed a distinction, however, thinking about it, it occurred to me that there are some interesting differences in usage regarding nouns and verb forms.  But you don't want an answer about that, right?

Comment: @z7sg: Maybe *I'd rather go blind* isn't the only one that doesn't sound right with the other word, and that might not be just because of [the song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ohx9Ve7-GS0). But you're right - I'm just asking whether *prefer* really does have a slightly more "formal" edge.

Comment: I've seen some English learning exercise books on Google which say *I'd rather = I'd prefer to*. Do you feel it's more formal perhaps because the *prefer* requires a *to* while *rather* does not.

Comment: @JoseK: It may be something to do with the extra "to", but it's not obvious to me why that should be so. Apart from my "gut feel", I'm only justifying my proposition based on the relative frequencies using the contracted form *"I'd"* as opposed to *"I would"*. My NGram links suggest that with the informal *"I'd"*, *rather* accounts for 90-95% of all instances, but this falls to 60-70% with *I would*. *Prefer* is always less common, but when it *does* occur, it's more likely to be in a non-contracted (i.e. - more formal) context.

Comment: NGrams for "I would prefer not to" may be inflated by hits on Melville's [Bartleby the Scrivener](http://www.bartleby.com/129/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider "I'd rather to not say" and "I'd prefer to not say". In my book they grammatically (even mathematically) equal so we can simply compare the two individual words which are different. Otherwise there's the obvious reason that you've used a more *grammatically* formal construction which makes "I'd [verb] to not say" more formal than "I'd [verb] not say".

'Prefer' has a Latin root (1) whereas 'rather' and 'sooner' (2) have the same old English root, cognate with many Germanic languages. Often using the Latin-derived words sounds more formal so that's probably why you think it's more formal. Historically Latin was the common language, especially in academic circles, between various European states and so naturally the "more educated" or "more formal" language would use Latin or Latin-derived words rather than old English.

1. **Prefer**: French and Middle French *préférer* from Latin *praeferō*.
2. **Rather**: Middle English *rether* from Old English *hraþor* from Proto-Germanic *hraþaz*

Comment: Well, it's true *I would rather not* **to** *[do sth]* has completely disappeared, but presumably that was the original "formal" construction. It certainly seems we're more prepared to bend the rules with *rather*. And it's true words taken from French often outclass OE words. Centuries ago because the Normans were our Conquerers, and today just because a bit of French adds a certain *je ne sais quoi*.

Comment: "I'd rather to not" isn't grammatical in my book. And nobody uses it, either. Compare [this Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rather+not+to%2C+rather+to+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [this Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rather+not+to%2Cwould+rather+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, "rather" is stronger - and therefore less polite - than "prefer," unless "prefer" is accompanied by a snooty tone.  "I'd prefer not to do that" definitely sounds not only more polite to my ears, but also more willing to do the thing if necessary.  "I'd rather not do that" seems to carry a more heavy reluctance, and to be a bit more casual as well.

n.b. I am a native speaker of English in the USA.

Comment: Yep! We love using the old English words to add punch and immediacy. Old French and Latin words lack immediacy and add officiousness :)