# What is the correct comparative and superlative expression for "I would like"?

Tags: expression-choice, comparatives

Is there any comparative expression that belongs straight to the non-comparative expression "I would like" - something like good, better, the best?

I always think of "I'd rather" but is it incorrect to say "I'd rather a cup of tea (instead of / than) a hot chocolate."?

And the superlative: "I'd most rather" or "I'd most like" + (a cup of tea.)?

Comment: The first is *prefer* -- "I'd prefer a cup of tea (instead of a hot chocolate)."

Comment: I would love a cup of tea?

Comment: Related: [I'd rather not do something vs I'd prefer not to do something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42317/)

Comment: Are you postulating a scenario where you'd rather A than B, *and* you'd rather C than D, and you want to convey that one of those preferences is stronger than the other? You can certainly say *I'd rather A than B, but I'd **much** rather C than D*, which would contextually imply that the latter preference is stronger. But I don't think English has any easy way of *explicitly* conveying that "second order preference" using the word ***rather*** (that's to say, ***more rather*** doesn't really work for me).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm happy with the "I'd rather A than B", it is a comparative between the two, expressing the preference of the A over B. Thanks for confirming the correctness of it.
As for the superlative, I was curious whether there is a way of saying it simply. What about "Most I'd like A"?

Comment: @DanielKatz You can say “I’d most like a cup of tea”, but it sounds a bit unusual. “I'd like a cup of tea most of all” is more normal-sounding, but there is no commonly-used way in English to express a superlative preference explicitly, unlike languages like German (_am liebsten_) for instance. You'd probably be most likely to hear something like, “But what I’d really like is a cup of tea”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> More than anything, I would like chamomile.
>
> Most of all, I would like hibiscus.

It's a little weird, though.  I had to put the "more" and "most" at the beginning to make it work.

I'm sorry, I have no idea how to document this.

Comment: It's a bit of a semantic gap in English, that's why it ends up being weird. We just don't tell to compare our preferences grammatically like this in English. Compare with German where you could easily say (with the disclaimer that my German grammar is dreadful), “Ich möchte gern einen Tee” (I’d like to have a cup of tea), “Ich möchte lieber einen Tee” (I'd more like a cup of tea), and “Ich möchte am liebsten einen Tee” (I'd most like a cup of tea). Without sounding odd.

Comment: In the thefreedictionary.com, I've found "They like sweets and biscuits but they like ice-cream most of all." I see that the "Most of all" is very common so that's probably what I sought.

Comment: @DanielKatz - Well, there you aren't trying to combine with "would."  Combining with "would" is what makes your question so challenging.  Without "would" there are more options, e.g. I like Cambria more than Times New Roman, but I like Garamond best [of all].

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, I was hoping to find something close to the thing I know in my language similar to "most preferably". Does this sound odd?: "Most preferably, I'd have a cup of tea." The "most of all" is a structure that works with or without the "would" so I forgot about it when I posted the dictionary example.

Comment: @DanielKatz - "Most preferably"  is unusual but I will give you permission to say it.  Non-native speakers of English are allowed to use unusual expressions when they can be clearly understood and are not annoying to the ear.  "Most preferably, I'd have a cup of tea"  is not only not annoying, it is also rather charming.  Please go right ahead.  Maybe you'll set a trend!

Comment: I should add that a native speaker might express this with "A cup of tea would be my first choice, but coffee would be fine too."